# Searching a tkinter dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

What I am attempting to create is a program that will first create a pandas dataframe. Then, it will make a tkinter window with an input entry frame, a button, and a text box. For the code I have below, when the button is pressed, I get an output that shows the header of the dataframe and the row that was "searched".

```
import pandas
from tkinter import *
#creates the dataframe
summer17=pandas.read_excel("summer17.xlsx","list")

window = Tk() #start of the main window
#function that will search the dataframe column "company" for any matches
def search_df():
    search_result=summer17[summer17['Company'].str.contains("CAPS")]
    t1.insert(END,search_result)
#Creates the entry box
e1_value=StringVar()
e1=Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0,column=0)
#Creates a button
b1=Button(window,width=10,text='search',command=search_df)
b1.grid(row=0,column=1)
#Creates a text box
t1=Text(window,height=5,width=80)
t1.grid(row=0,column=2)

window.mainloop() #end of the main window
```

That works all and well, however, I want the user to be able to input a value into the entry box and press the button and search for that entry. So I change the function to be

```
def search_df():
    search_result=summer17[summer17['Company'].str.contains(e1_value.get())]
    t1.insert(END,search_result)
```

If I leave this blank, it returns the entire data frame (as I may or may not expect). However, if I put CAPS in the entry box and press the button, It still returns the entire dataframe.

My guess is that when I am getting the value from the entry box, there is a variable miss match, but I'm not sure how I would correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used one of my files to create the dataframe.

you need to add the e1_value to the entry by using the textvariable parameter.

I added a bind between the enter key and your function therefore you don't have to press the button, you can press the enter key instead. To do that, i used the bind function. This function binds a widget and a tkinter event. it executes the chosen function and passes a parameter (which is the event).

However the command paramter of the widget button **does not pass any parameter** when it executes the chosen function (the event is always a left clic). That's why your function takes *event as a parameter, event can be None. (i used *event but event=None works too, and i don't know which way is the most pythonic way, sorry)

PS : You should use `import tkinter as tk` because you may have some conflict with variable and function names if you use `from tkinter import *`

```
import pandas
import tkinter as tk
#creates the dataframe
summer17=pandas.read_csv("User_AD_Commun01_2017-07-26_15-01.csv",
                         sep=";",
                         encoding="latin1")




window = tk.Tk() #start of the main window
#function that will search the dataframe column "company" for any matches


def search_df(*event):
    search_result=summer17.loc[summer17['company'].str.contains(e1_value.get(),
                               na=False, #ignore the cell's value is Nan
                               case=False)] #case insensitive
    t1.insert(tk.END,search_result)


#Creates the entry box and link the e1_value to the variable
e1_value=tk.StringVar()
e1=tk.Entry(window, textvariable=e1_value)
e1.grid(row=0,column=0)
#execute the search_df function when you hit the "enter" key and put an event
#parameter
e1.bind("<Return>", search_df) 

#Creates a button
b1=tk.Button(window,
             width=10,
             text='search',
             command=search_df)

b1.grid(row=0,column=1)

#Creates a text box
t1=tk.Text(window,height=5,width=80)
t1.grid(row=0,column=2)

window.mainloop() #end of the main window
```

Comment: Watch out my colunm name is company and  your column name is Company

Comment: This is fantastic, I would never have thought to add the *event. I guess that's what you get for teaching yourself a computer language. Also, thanks for adding the function to just push enter, and the case=False. Those are some features I wanted to add but was lower on the priority list.